# Jquery variable not set

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the top part of my document I have this Jquery code:

```
// RATING 
$('.rateit').click(function(){
var position = $(this).position();
});
```

In the footer I have a ajax call:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
             url: frm.attr('action'), //your server side script
             data: frm.serialize(), //our data
             type: 'POST',
             success: function (data) {
            alert(position.left);
            },
```

The problem is that the alert box is not showing with the position. I have tested with `alert('something');` and it works fine.

My real ajax call:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
     url: frm.attr('action'), //your server side script
     data: frm.serialize(), //our data
     type: 'POST',
     success: function (data) {
    $('.warning').fadeIn(500).css({display: 'block',
        position: 'absolute',
        left: position.left + 50,
        top: position.top - 25
    }).append('asdasdsadsad'),
    $(ri).next('.ratingcount').html('asdasdasd')
    },
     error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
         alert(msg); //something went wrong.
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `position` inside the anonymous function used as a click event handler. That means it won't be in scope when you try to alert it (you will get a ReferenceError).

You will need to declare `position` outside of the event handler function:

```
var position;
$('.rateit').click(function(){
    position = $(this).position();
});
```

However, you will still get an error if the click event handler hasn't been executed when your `alert` runs, because `position` will be `undefined` and therefore won't have a `left` property.

Comment: Still the position is not set in the ajax call.

Comment: I have updated my question with my real ajax call. The position is not set for the div warning.

Comment: @Railsbeginner That's because your `position` variable is set in response to an event from the user (clicking on an element), and your AJAX call is simply fired off as soon as the code is loaded.

Comment: what is a solution for that problem?

Comment: @Railsbeginner Either fire off the AJAX call in response to the same event or get the position in the `success` callback function for the AJAX call. Or both, I guess.

Comment: @Railsbeginner why dont you get the position inside the ajax success call back

Answer (score 3):

On click function, position is a local variable, so will only be visible in this scope.

Try this:

```
var position;

$('.rateit').click(function(){
    position = $(this).position();
});
```

Comment: I have updated my question with my full ajax call. The position is not set for the warning div.

Comment: When this ajax is called? You need set position before Ajax call, not on click.

Comment: Or call ajax function on click `.rateit` element.

Answer (score 0):

I's because your variable is defined inside $('.rateit').click(); try that:

```
var position;

$('.rateit').click(function(){
position = $(this).position();
});
```